# zsh: PageUp in menu completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, zle

In my `.zshrc` I have

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=20
```

This way when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, I receive a menu of completions (assuming there are at least 20 to choose from). I can then navigate it using <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys. I would expect <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> to scroll up/down a page, but that is not the default behavior.

A natural idea is to use `bindkey` to bind <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> to appropriate commands. However, I can find only `up-line-or-history` and `down-line-or-history` in the docs, but not their page analogues. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menu completion invokes the [menu selection code form the `zsh/complist` module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Menu-selection). This module only allows a limited selection of commands, but this does include “moves the mark one screenful up/down”. Oddly, you have to bind the key to `forward-word`/`backward-word` or one of their variants — presumably because the menu selection code reuses standard widgets and there's no standard widget for page up/down, whereas menu selection doesn't have words as such.

You can use the [terminfo](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fterminfo-Module) module to [look up the key sequences](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=terminfo&sektion=5) that <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> send, or hard-code the ones that your terminal sends.

```
zmodload zsh/complist
zmodload zsh/terminfo
bindkey -M menuselect $terminfo[kpp] backward-word
bindkey -M menuselect $terminfo[knp] forward-word
```

Comment: I had to add `zmodload zsh/complist` to the `.zshrc` file to load the module before invoking `bindkey`, and then it worked. I guess that the module gets autoloaded when the completion is invoked, but before the module is loaded the keymap `menuselect` is not defined. An additional thanks for the pointer to `terminfo` module.